# What are the contours / limits of waiver in Florida HOA law?

Tags: waivers

Are there any rules of thumbs as to what is waivable? or what is not waivable?  How long one has to act in order not to be waived?

It have observed that if one does not complain about the neighbors or an HOA's transgression in a timely manner, then opposing counsel will engage waiver is a defense.

Answer (score -1):

### Everything is waivable

Waive simply means that a person gives up or forgoes their legal rights; usually, by simply accepting the status quo.

In terms of a HOA, the HOA can waive any of its rights vis-a-vis a member(s) and vice-versa. Because the relationship between a HOA and its members is not a contractual one, such a waiver does not need to be supported by consideration.

While a waiver can be explicit, it can also be implicit, particularly where the right is being violated in an open and notorious way. Because most remedies that are sought from breach of HOA rules are [equitable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equitable_remedy) (like an injunction); [laches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laches_(equity)) applies:

> The person invoking laches is asserting that an opposing party has "slept on its rights", and that, as a result of this delay, circumstances have changed, witnesses or evidence may have been lost or no longer available, etc.<sup>1</sup>, such that it is no longer a just resolution to grant the plaintiff's claim. Laches is associated with the maxim of equity, "Equity aids the vigilant, not the sleeping ones" who sleep on their rights. Put another way, failure to assert one's rights in a timely manner can result in a claim being barred by laches.

<sup>1</sup> Or expensive building work might have taken place.

Comment: -1 There are various circumstances in which law, particularly consumer protection and landlord/tenant laws, specifically forbid waiver, or at least contractual or advance waiver, of certain rights. (US Copyright law has such a provision also: termination rights may not be contracted away.) One may choose not to exercise certain rights, but to waive them is to permanently forgo them, at least in a specific case. I don't know if Florida HOA law has any such provisions, but "*Everything is waivable*" is simply incorrect

Comment: @DavidSiegel if you do not act on a right in a timely manner, it cannot be enforced. While technically different from a waiver, practically there is no difference.

Comment: In some cases that is  true, particularly when the remedy derives from equity. In other cases it is not true. Copyrights, for example, can be enforced at any time, even after years of delay. Rights to real estate can be enforced unless the delay is so long as to constitute adverse possession (10 years or more in many places). Recent laws in child abuse cases have allowed claims 30+ years after the fact in some places. There are other rights which delay does not waive, ad ones where there is a statute of limitations,. but any claim within the statutory period is valid.